# XPath Wildcards for HTML

Tags: html, dom, xpath, wildcard

I'm using XPath to extract DOM elements values.
Since the XPaths aren't consistent, I'm using some wildcard magic to select all DOM elements on the same level.

Example XPaths in HTML document:

```
//div[@id='floatswrap']/div/div[2]/div[1]
//div[@id='floatswrap']/div/div[2]/div[2]
//div[@id='floatswrap']/div/div[2]/div[3]
......
//div[@id='floatswrap']/div/div[2]/div[100]
```

I've tried the `*/div[@id='floatswrap']/div/div[2]/div` wildcard (note the asterisk character at the beginning and no square brackets at end), but it fails.
So I'm using the following (example code for above):
`//div[@id='floatswrap']/div/div[2]/div[*]` (note the asterisk inside brackets) and it woks for now.

Since I'm new to XPath, is there a better and more consistent way to make XPath node selection using wildcards?

**EDIT:**
Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
    <body>
      <div id="floatswrap">
        <div>
         <div>First</div>
         <div>                     <!-- SELECT ALL DIV NODES WRAPPED IN THIS DIV -->
          Second

           <div>One</div>                     <!-- SELECT THIS NODE -->
           <div>Two</div>                     <!-- SELECT THIS NODE -->
           <div>Three</div>                   <!-- SELECT THIS NODE -->
           <!-- ........ -->                  <!-- SELECT ALL DIV NODES -->
           <div>Hundred</div>                 <!-- SELECT THIS NODE -->
         </div> <!-- ./Second DIV -->
       </div>
       <div> Some Text </div>         
       <div> Some Other Text </div>
      </div> <!-- ./floatswrap -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to select all DIVs in the second DIV.

Comment: IDs are unique, so useing `//div[@id=...]` is reasonable. Without any example input, no further comment on what's following can be made. Please post at least the whole div, and also expected output.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish here is to iterate through DOM nodes under certain DOM node defined as an XPath string.

Comment: But by using wildcards. I can accomplish this with other environment, or using CSS selectors, but having this on XPath level seems much faster and have possibilities to dynamically define if in a runtime.

Comment: If you have a question for this single use case, please post input so somebody can answer it. As is, it cannot really be answered, all we can do is guesswork what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JensErat I've edited the question. Please take a look above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not give any predicate, no additionally filters (but for the element name, here div) will be applied. `div[*]` is actually not *exactly* doing what you need; it only selects divs with other child nodes.

This will select all of the div's you want to have:

```
//div[@id='floatswrap']/div/div[2]/div
```

You might want to add a positional predicate to the second axis step if it returns too much:

```
//div[@id='floatswrap']/div[1]/div[2]/div
```

Further simplification does not seem possible; you might be able to select only div's not containing other elements, but I don't think that this is better in any fashion:

```
//div[@id='floatswrap']//div[not(*)]
```